# Share file from url with React Native

Tags: android, ios, react-native, share

I already manage to use `{ Share } from 'react-native'` to send message with other app (WhatsApp for example).

Now, I want to share a file from url (mp3), and not just the url link.
I didn't find the case, and I try something like this, but it didn't work:

```
react import { Share } from 'react-native'

Share.share({
                  url: "https//www.website.com/mymp3.mp3",
            })
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Try this,

 in your render(){

<Button onPress={() => this.onClickShare()}> Share </Button>

}

your custom function,

onClickShare = async () => {
    try {
      const result = await Share.share({
        message:
          "https//www.website.com/mymp3.mp3",
      });
    } catch (error) {
      alert(error.message);
    }
  };
```

Its very simple.....
**p.n.** - you can write **url:** prop by checking the platform==="ios" in place of **message**, as it is for ios, in android it takes a link automatically.

Comment: Thanks you for your help! But it's share the link https//www.website.com/mymp3.mp3, not directly the mp3 file. I don't know if it's possible.